# Links are loading without thumbnail images in Facebook and links are unreachable in Website

Tags: hyperlink, facebook-social-plugins

Some of our links from website Pixorange.com is loading without thumbnail images, while we try to share it in FB wall. Also, the FB official plugin in our websites shows that some of our URL is unreachable. We did contact server support and they told us that everything is fine from their end.

This is an intermittent issue, some links work fine, whereas other links never work. This is creating problem for us and we are not able to promote our business in Facebook.

These are the links wherein we are not able to load in FB status, links keep on changes:

http://pixorange.com/rajiv-gandhi-was-entrepreneur-for-swedish-jet

http://pixorange.com/urinal-dedicated-to-politician-ajit-pawar-by-opponents

Also on some links the title does not fetch up and URL gets replaced for it. This is going to be a serious issue for us. Please help us to resolve this issue.

**Steps to Reproduce:** Here is the steps to reproduce the issue:

1. Go to below link
2. select the above links and share it in Facebook wall or try to comment in plugin :

The above links will not get posted in FB wall and also there will no thumbnails with it. Since we are online magazine we do update lots of posts daily, some links will get posted without any issue and some does not.

**Expected Behavior:**  The link should get posted as normal with thumbnail in it.
**Actual Behavior:**    Link will not be posted in users Facebook wall.

After debugging, we get 200 response even after waiting for some time, link won't work

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with Facebook share Thumbnails that Facebook is aware of. This has been an issue on and off for the past 3 months now... check out this [link](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10200708365214182&referer=search_result&query=share%20thumbnail)

Comment: I did open up a ticket in developers tool. I did not received any update on it. Some links works well and some does not. That's the main issue. We are not able to promote our magazine